# Not getting previous image in 1st case itself

Tags: android

Am beginner to android..I developed an app like if i press prev and next button it will display prevous and next images....

But I had issue in my app..The problem here was, if app execute i set an current image source as **IMAGE_IDS[0]**... So that if i pressed left arrow app gets **force close**, actually if i press left arrow it shows last image in the **array IMAGE_IDS**... Any idea ???   Thank You !

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements OnClickListener{

    ImageButton play;

    ImageButton ib_left_arrow, ib_right_arrow;  

    ImageView slidingimage;

    Animation rotateimage;  


    private int[] IMAGE_IDS = { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3};

    int imglength=IMAGE_IDS.length;

    int img_position;

    int img_minus;

    int img_plus;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.movies);


    ib_left_arrow = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iv_left_arrow);
    ib_right_arrow = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.iv_right_arrow);

    ib_left_arrow.setOnClickListener(this);
    ib_right_arrow.setOnClickListener(this);

    slidingimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView3_Left);
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[0]);

}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


switch (v.getId()) {

case R.id.iv_left_arrow:


    img_minus=--img_position;

    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[img_minus% IMAGE_IDS.length]);

    rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.slide_in_left);

    slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);

    break;



case R.id.iv_right_arrow:

    img_plus=++img_position;

    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[img_plus% IMAGE_IDS.length]);

    rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.slide_in_right);

    slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);


    break;              


    }
  }


 }
```

Comment: do you want the app to be closed when pressing left arrow and img_position = 0?

Comment: lelloman : No, if img_position = 0 then if i press left arrow it should show the previous image from  last in array ( (last image from array)....... Like pedalling the cycle reverse....

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is `img_plus% IMAGE_IDS.length` when setting the image position in the array.

I would try:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    img_position = 0;
    imglength = IMAGE_IDS.length;
    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[img_position]);

// ...
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.iv_left_arrow:

            img_position--;    
            break;

        case R.id.iv_right_arrow:

            img_position++;
            break;

    }

    // this is to check if your current position is out of array bounds, you could
    // handle here your exit if you want to close the app when pressing left and 
    // img_position = 0 || img_position < 0
    if(img_position < 0) img_position = imglength-1;
    if(img_position >= imglength) img_position = imglength -1;

    slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[img_position]);
```

Comment: lelloman : Your code works fine...but in 1st case if i pressed previous button image not showing previous image (last image from array)...

Comment: @NaveenR ok, I edited the code, `if(img_position < 0) img_position = imglength-1;` like this, if you press left and the selected image is 0 it should go to the last one in the array. I didn't understand if you wanted the app to close when pressing left on image 0 :)

Comment: **lelloman** : This line also works fine man **if(img_position < 0) img_position = imglength-1;** , but one issue was after i pressed **right arrow** and so on it wont show the **next image** ( ex : if am in **image_3**, if i press next button it would show **image_1** and so on and also if i press **previous button** it would show the **previous image** from current image and so on ...clear...Thank you..!!

Comment: @NaveenR I'm afraid I didn't get your last issue, if you press right arrow it will icrease `img_position`, if `img_position` reaches `imglength` it will be reset to 0, did you set `imglength`'s value to the array length? I'm going to add this line to the answer. btw, if it works please accept the answer ^^

Comment: wats afraid in that issue man..simple... if am in **image_3** (last image from an array), if i press **right arrow** it would show the **first image(image_1)** again and so on.... but i dunno how to reset the **imagelength**.... Can u help me ...pls...thank you...

Comment: @NaveenR why would you reset `imagelength`? `imagelength` is the variable that let you know when the loop of images ends (or starts). it equals `array.length` and you would not change it, unless the array changes size. in fact, you could just use `array.length` instead. I'm afraid I really don't understand what's the problem now.

Comment: lelloman  : Thanks for ur replies....Just run the above code and u came to know about the issue....Just click **Left_arrow** and **Right_arrow** so on....and tell me...pls

Comment: @NaveenR I'm sorry but I'm not going to set up an android project to come to know something that you could just explain in plain english...I told what I thought was wrong with your code, if that's not enough you should be able to point out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

### imgposition=0;

```
  case R.id.iv_left_arrow:

        if(0<img_position){        
        --img_position;

        slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[img_position]);

        rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.slide_in_left);

        slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);}

        break;



    case R.id.iv_right_arrow:
    if(2>=counter)
{ 
        ++img_position;

        slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[img_position]);

        rotateimage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.slide_in_right);

        slidingimage.startAnimation(rotateimage);}


        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its happening because of this line

```
img_minus=--img_position;
```

and this calculation

```
img_plus % IMAGE_IDS.length
```

If it's at 0 then

```
img_minus=--img_position;//img_minus = --0 therefore img_minus = -1

//img_plus % IMAGE_IDS.length // -1 % 3 = 2
slidingimage.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[2]);//which is the last image.
```

So if you want to close the Activity if left is pressed then

```
img_minus=--img_position;
if(img_minus < 0({
    finish();
    return;
}
```